# NoRouteToHost Exception

Tags: java, sockets, socketexception

I can SSH and PING a machine running Fedora 18, but whenever I try connect to it using Sockets, I get NoRouteToHostException (I tried Java and C++, and I get the same error).

Any ideas? I have looked around but could not find a solution that works.

Comment: Are you trying to connect by name or by address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not trying to connect to the same port that ssh(1) uses (port 22) then the problem could be that a firewall exists between you and the destination and it doesn't allow your packets through. You can test this by having your code try to connect to port 22 on the destination host. If you don't get the same exception, then this is the likely cause.

You should also verify that your code is OK by having it try to connect to the local host (i.e., the computer on which it's running). You should not get the no-route-to-host exception  (unless the firewall on the local host is doing something odd)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was certainly a firewall problem